# Pod-to-service communication with Kubernetes and Flannel

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I have recently set up a multi-machine Kubernetes cluster w/ Docker and Flannel. I have set up Flannel on a subnet `172.16.0.0/24` such that a container on host A with an assigned IP of `172.16.78.2` can ping a container on host B with an assigned IP of `172.16.74.2`.

I have Kubernetes set up with all of its various components (`kubelet`, `kube-proxy` `kube-apiserver`, `kube-scheduler`, `kube-controller-manager`) and I can successfully launch deployments and pods around the cluster.

### Problem

I deployed a Redis service and my webapp pod onto the cluster. On my webapp pod, the environmental variables `REDIS_SERVICE_HOST` and `REDIS_SERVICE_PORT` are set, but `REDIS_SERVICE_HOST` is a random IP on the `172.16.0.0/16` subnet. To be clear, if I run `ifconfig` and get the IP address for `eth0` in the Redis container, I can ping that from my webapp pod. But not the IP address assigned to `REDIS_SERVICE_HOST`.

I'm fairly certain this is a configuration problem, but here are some flags I'm setting for each service:

#### kube-proxy arguments

- `--cluster-cidr 172.16.0.0/16`

#### kube-apiserver arguments

- `--service-cluster-ip-range=172.16.0.0/16`

#### kube-controller-manager arguments

- `--cluster-cidr=172.16.0.0/16`
- `--service-cluster-ip-range=172.16.0.0/16`

I'm not really sure how the above flags work in conjunction to Flannel, but I tried a lot of things, and I couldn't get anything to work. Some explanation on how these things work would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, after playing around and reading more issues, I figured out that I don't have a problem here at all. From here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7996, I learned that pinging a service doesn't do anything. I hadn't actually tried to connect to the service up to now, but I did, and it worked.

Above, I used a CIDR of `172.16.0.0/16`, which is the Flannel subnet. That's wrong, and it should actually be something that doesn't overlap with Flannel's subnet. I'll verify all of this and make sure it works across multiple nodes.